# Having trouble using regular expressions with the split method in java

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a list of strings that I need to parse for the name and version, for example some strings look like this:

App Name 1.2.5
AppName 7.8.b
The App Name 7.0

I want to have two list of Strings one with the app name and one with the version number so one list is:

App Name
AppName
The App Name

Then the other list will be

1.2.5
7.8.b
3.0

I have tried just using a space to split the strings, but it would be easiest if the name was always in index 0 and the version is always in index 1. So I tried "\\d" (split by digits), however that didn't work like I thought it was. Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split isn't really appropriate here.  Try using a matcher instead and use the [`group`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) method to get the app name and version.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\D*[^\\d\\s])\\s*(\\d.*)", Pattern.DOT_ALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
  String appName = m.group(1);
  String versionNumber = m.group(2);
  ...
}
```

To understand how the regular expression works, take a look at the below:

```
^
```

means start matching at the start

```
(
```

starts group 1 which will hold the version name

```
\\D*
```

which starts with any number of non-digits

```
[^\\d\\s]
```

and ends with something that is neither a digit nor a space.

```
)
```

end of group 1

```
\\s*
```

which might be separated from the version number by zero or more spaces.

(

Group 2 contains the version number.

```
\\d
```

It starts with a digit

```
.*
```

and continues the rest of the input.

```
)
```

The end.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `" (?=\\d)"`

that is a space followed by an digit which is not *consumed* (via zero-width positive lookahead)